# Regular expressions in JavaScript with the global flag

Tags: javascript

It appears that the `RegExp` intrinsic is stateful.

So calling it twice on the same string will yield different results when the global flag `g` is supplied, as it advances a search along the string.

So:

```js
var r = /(\d{3})/g;
    
console.log(r.test('123')); // true
console.log(r.test('123')); // false - because the search has moved past the first match
```

But if I add an intermediate test, I get the following:

```js
var r = /(\d{3})/g;
    
console.log(r.test('123')); // true
console.log(r.test('456')); // true
console.log(r.test('123')); // true!
```

So is it correct to say that `RegExp` instances operate on the principle of considering only the last string evaluated? If the string differs from the last, it is effectively reset?

Comment: Short answer with at least 15 characters: **yes**

Comment: Please make that the answer and I'll accept...

Comment: If the global flag is omitted, is the regular expression reset in between tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So is it correct to say that RegExp instances operate on the principle of considering only the last string evaluated?

yes

> If the string differs from the last, it is effectively reset?

correct

> If the global flag is omitted, is the regular expression reset in between tests?

right

Check out [RegExp#lastIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex)